# Drupal designing themes on a different server

Tags: ruby, drupal, drupal-7

I am developing drupal themes using omega 4. A lot of the theme depends on sass and ruby extensions, which is great and I would like to develop towards this trend, however, we have a managed server which does not allow for ruby gems to be installed. I think the best solution is to design all my themes on my own personal server and then just copy the theme over to the primary site.

## Question 1

- Would this be a practical choice ?

## Question 2

- As far as I know, all the sass and ruby extensions are only necissary for development of the theme and layout, as they are all compiled into css at the end of the day. So if I'm correct, I won't need them installed on the end server if I'm not developing or changing them too much ?

T.I.A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your approach is the correct one. As you say in your question 2, sass, and expecially ruby, are only needed in a development environment, so you don't need to install them on the production server. It may also be safer not to publish your development files in the production server, so you won't let trace on the public server of your development process.

Be sure to compile your CSS files with

```
environment = :production
```

in your `config.rb` file before publishing to production.